# Jmockit/Spring mocked dependency still calls the Real dependency

Tags: spring, jmockit

so I've been stuck on this problem all day.

I'm testing a class of type JdbcSupportDao in Spring 3.2.  The problem is very self-explanatory if you just read the code, but I will briefly summarize:

I use the @Mocked annotation on a JdbcTemplate to mock querying the database.  The problem is, after writing the Expectations block, the actual JdbcTemplate method is still being called, with JMockit apparently not entering in to the equation at all.

The following unit test fails:

```
/*@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)*/
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:studentAggregateReport-servlet.xml", "classpath:applicationContext-hibernate.xml"})
public class JdbcSSODaoTest   extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Mocked
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    List<String> unameList;


    SSODao ssoDao;

    String DUMMY_ALCID = "yattayattayatta";

    @Before
    public void constructDao() {
        this.ssoDao = new JdbcSSODao();
        ((JdbcSSODao) ssoDao).setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetUnameFromAlcId() {
        unameList = new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("PEEPEE");
        }};
        //((JdbcSSODao) ssoDao).setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
        new Expectations() {{
            jdbcTemplate.query(anyString, (ResultSetExtractor<String>)any); result = unameList;
        }};

        String uname = ssoDao.getUnameFromAlcId(DUMMY_ALCID);

        assertNotNull(uname);
    }

}
```

and here is the code for the class being tested:

```
public class JdbcSSODao extends JdbcDaoSupport implements SSODao {

    @Override
    public String getUnameFromAlcId(String alcid) {
        String sql = SSOSqlUtil.createGetUnameByAlcIdSql(alcid);
        logger.debug(sql);
        List<String> resultLst = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new RowMapper<String>() {
            public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                return rs.getString(1);
            }
        });
        if(resultLst.isEmpty()) return null;
        return resultLst.get(0);
    }

}
```

Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Sweet mother of God..

Apparently, you have to cast parameters of mocked methods to the exact type used in the call.  This fixed it for me:

```
    new Expectations() {{
        jdbcTemplate.query(anyString, (RowMapper<String>)any); result = unameList;
    }};
```